# how to add trailing icon in multiple line text

Tags: flutter

I need your help. I need to implement the UI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiKMX.png)

I use RichText + WidgetSpan, but it's not work. if the current text is more than two lines long, i got the effect like this, it's wrong. I need the icon must show:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuw83.png)

What I want to resolve is that more than two lines will display the ellipsis, while the trailing icon will still be displayed

If it's one-line text， I can use Row + Expaned, but the multiple line text with icon mixed, can only use RichText + WidgetSpan

I also considered using TextPainter to calculate boundary values, but it didn't feel like an optimal solution

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I have a solution for this but not a good example to do. You can wrap it with stack widget then maybe the icon positioned it on the bottom right. Im hoping if the icon always at the bottom right..

Comment: yeah, thanks for your answer, I've already thought of that；But the key point is how do you determine if the current text is more than two lines long.trailing icon wasn't always there

Comment: sorry i made a mistake,  ellipses don't always exist, not icon

Answer (score 1):

A `RichText` widget can be used with a
`TextSpan` (For the initial text)
+
`WidgetSpan`(For the text with backgroundColor / icon)
to create such an output.

Here is a code snippet with the output using the widgets described above:

**Output:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(children: [
        TextSpan(
          text:
              "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.... ",
        ),
        WidgetSpan(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1, left: 6, right: 6),
            child: Text(
              "Read more",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(4),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,What I want to resolve is that more than two lines will display the ellipsis, while the ending icon will still be displayed